# Rails Postgres, select users with relation and group them based on users starting time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have Users and Checkpoint tables, each User can make multiple Checkpoints per day

I want to aggregate how many Checkpoints had been taken each day in the past 6 months based on each user's starting point, to create a graph showing avarage user Checkpoints witin thier x months.

for example:
if user1 started on January 1st, user2 started on March 15th, and user3 started on July 6th those would each be considered day 1, I would want the data from each of their day 1 even though they occur at different periods of time.

The current query I came up with, but unfotunatily it returns data based on fixed time for all of the users.

```
SELECT dates.date AS date,
       checkpoints_count,
       checkpoints_users
FROM (SELECT DATE_TRUNC('DAY', ('2000-01-01'::DATE - offs))::DATE AS date
      -- 180 = 6 month in days
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 180) AS offs) AS dates
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            checkpoints_date::DATE  AS date,
            COUNT(id)               AS checkpoints_count,
            COUNT(user_id)          AS checkpoints_users
        FROM checkpoints
        WHERE user_id in (1, 2, 3)
        AND checkpoints_date::DATE
        BETWEEN '2000-01-01'::DATE AND '2000-06-01'::DATE
        GROUP BY checkpoints_date::DATE
    ) AS ck
    ON dates.date = ck.date
ORDER BY dates.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Here is a working SQL example that works (If I understand what you are looking for. Your SQL seems really complicated for what you are asking but I'm not a SQL expert)...

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM checkpoints AS t1
WHERE t1.user_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
AND t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
             FROM checkpoints AS t2
             WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id            
             ORDER BY t2.check_date ASC
             LIMIT 1)
```

[SQL FIDDLE here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4f9d2/4)

Since this is tagged Ruby on Rails I'll give you a rails answer.

If you know your user IDs (or use some other query to get them you have:

```
user_ids = [1, 2, 3]
first_checkpoints = []
user_ids.each do |id|
  first_checkpoints << Checkpoint.where(user_id: id).order(:date).first
end

#returns an array of the first checkpoint of each user in list
```

This assumes a column in the `checkpoints` table called `date`. You didn't give a table structure for the two tables so this answer is a bit general. There  might be a pure ActiveRecord answer. But this will get you what you want.